# Windows Phone - C# - How do I create a TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.8

It's pretty simple, but how do you create a TextBox in C#?

I need to place it within a ListBox at a certain location (before the last item of the ListBox).

I need the new TextBox to contain properties about it's Text, Name, and Width.

Here's the sample of code in .xaml, I need the `TextBox` to be placed above the `Image`

```
<ListBox Margin="0,-20,0,0" Height="548" Name="listBoxNew">
    <TextBlock Name="textBlockName" Text="Name"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBoxName" Width="420" Margin="-12,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBlock Name="textBlockAdd" Text="Add" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Name="textBoxAdd" Width="420" Margin="-12,0,0,0"/>
    <Image Name="imageAdd" Source="/SecondApp%2b;component/Images/buttonAdd1.png" Height="50" Margin="0,5,0,0" Tap="imageAdd_Tap" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" ManipulationStarted="imageAddExersize_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="imageAddExersize_ManipulationCompleted" />
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    // Add the last item to the listbox again
    listBox.Items.Add(listBox.Items.Last());

    // Place the textbox in the previous item
    listBox.Items[listBox.Items.Count - 2] = new TextBox();
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, it brought up an error at the `listBox.Items.Last());` section (I renamed listBox to the appropriate name by the way).

Comment: try `listBox.Items[litBox.Items.Count-1]` then

Comment: No, that didn't work, it replaced the Image, I added a sample of .xaml code if that helps

Comment: Also this procedure needs to be able to be recursive, the event that triggers the procedure is attached to the image.